# Blazor WebAssembly project live update not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have create a blazor web assembly project and trying to do some POC but some feature like Live refresh is not working. I need to build & run my project every time after any changes. Could you please help me out in this case?

[image]

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  Maybe show the code/method that you are trying to update....

Comment: Any things like html, css, js and class file. if i changed then new to rebuild

Comment: You can just run the project with CTRL+F5 and refresh the page without building again and it should work as you are expecting.

Comment: Hey! Really it works Thanks

Comment: HI I am getting an error if suddenly after doing this. You can check in attached in screen shot